# CRM 2011 Custom Chart - Two-State Field - Plot Both Values

Tags: c#, xml, charts, dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 I have several records that contain a two-state (nullable boolean) field.  I would like to plot a bar chart that counts the number of true and false values over all the records and plot them in the same chart (a bar for 'true' records and a bar for 'false' records).

Here is the modified XML I (originally generated using CRM) and for the life of me I can't figure out how to plot a chart with the 2 values, I have multiple records per month so the horizontal axis is the records cretedOn date (month).

Can anyone exaplin how I would modify the XML to achieve this?  Or point me to a resource that explains what to do?

```
    <visualization>
  <visualizationid>{CCA96081-E319-E211-B2CA-0800273EE9D1}</visualizationid>
  <name>Compliance Stages 1 &amp; 2, Chart 1</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>intellic_suppliersalesprocess</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
          <entity name="intellic_suppliersalesprocess">
            <attribute alias="aggregate_column" name="intellic_csvfileimported" aggregate="count" />
        <filter>
           <condition attribute="intellic_csvfileimported" operator="eq" value="true" />
        </filter>
        <attribute alias="aggregate_column1" name="intellic_csvfileimported" aggregate="count" />
        <filter>
           <condition attribute="intellic_csvfileimported" operator="eq" value="false" />
        </filter>
            <attribute groupby="true" alias="groupby_column" dategrouping="month" name="createdon" />
          </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category>
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="aggregate_column" />
          </measurecollection>
      <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="aggregate_column1" />
          </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart>
      <Series>
    <Series IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Color="110, 20, 78" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="141, 44, 45" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40"></Series>
        <Series IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Color="55, 118, 193" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="41, 88, 145" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40"></Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
          <AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorGrid LineColor="239, 242, 246" />
            <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisY>
          <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181" IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
            <MajorGrid LineColor="Transparent" />
            <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
          </AxisX>
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59"></Title>
      </Titles>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```

Any adivce would be much apprecited.

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two series, and each needs to do an aggregate on the count of records, but for a filtered set of records according to your bit field.
So while a typical two series chart might plot number of new Accounts and number of new Leads (say) in each month, here you want to plot the same entity twice, in each case do a count, but filter the records being counted. 
As a useful example to compare against, there is a built-in chart which shows Opportunities as deals won vs deals lost. In this example it does a sum of Actual Revenue for all Opportunities won, and a sum of estimated revenue for Opps lost. You can find this chart and export it, I have pasted below for ease of reference:

```
<visualization>
      <visualizationid>{C1CB81B1-575F-DF11-AE90-00155D2E3002}</visualizationid>
      <name>Deals Won vs. Deals Lost By Owner</name>
      <description>Shows the amount of revenue for won deals versus lost deals.</description>
      <primaryentitytypecode>opportunity</primaryentitytypecode>
      <datadescription>
        <datadefinition>
          <fetchcollection>
            <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
              <entity name="opportunity">
                <link-entity name="opportunity" from="opportunityid" to="opportunityid" link-type="outer">
                  <attribute alias="sum_lost" name="estimatedvalue" aggregate="sum"></attribute>
                  <filter>
                    <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="2" />
                  </filter>
                </link-entity>
                <link-entity name="opportunity" from="opportunityid" to="opportunityid" link-type="outer">
                  <attribute alias="sum_won" name="actualvalue" aggregate="sum"></attribute>
                  <filter>
                    <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
                  </filter>
                </link-entity>
                <attribute groupby="true" alias="groupby_column" name="ownerid"></attribute>
              </entity>
            </fetch>
          </fetchcollection>
          <categorycollection>
            <category>
              <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="sum_won" />
              </measurecollection>
              <measurecollection>
                <measure alias="sum_lost" />
              </measurecollection>
            </category>
          </categorycollection>
        </datadefinition>
      </datadescription>
      <presentationdescription>
        <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="97,142,206; 168,203,104; 209,98,96; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83; 148,172,215; 217,148,147; 189,213,151; 173,158,196; 145,201,221; 255,180,138">
          <Series>
            <Series Name="o:opportunity_statecode,1" Color="149, 189, 66" IsValueShownAsLabel="False" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="112, 142, 50" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
            </Series>
            <Series Name="o:opportunity_statecode,2" Color="255,124,31" IsValueShownAsLabel="False" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackSecondaryColor="235,98,0" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59">
              <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
            </Series>
          </Series>
          <ChartAreas>
            <ChartArea BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
              <AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181">
                <MajorGrid LineColor="239, 242, 246" />
                <MajorTickMark LineColor="165, 172, 181" />
                <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
              </AxisY>
              <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" TitleForeColor="59, 59, 59" TitleFont="{0}, 10.5px" LineColor="165, 172, 181">
                <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                <MajorTickMark Enabled="False" />
                <LabelStyle Font="{0}, 10.5px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
              </AxisX>
            </ChartArea>
          </ChartAreas>
          <Titles>
            <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
          </Titles>
          <Legends>
            <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="Bottom" Font="{0}, 11px" ForeColor="59, 59, 59"></Legend>
          </Legends>
        </Chart>
      </presentationdescription>
      <isdefault>false</isdefault>
    </visualization>
```

Notice the "filter" tags in each link-entity? Also see that there are two "measure collections" which define the series, and two entries for the presentation of these eg the colour.